# How to set shiro principal's property as thymeleaf tag attribute?

Tags: thymeleaf, shiro

I have a demand that I want to use a shiro principal's property as thymeleaf tag's attribute.

I use the lib thymeleaf-extras-shiro, it's true to use like this.

```
<a>
    <shiro:principal property='imgUrl'/>
</a>
```

but I want to set the property 'imgUrl' as tag '' attribute 'href'.

so anybody could tell me about this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at thymeleaf-extras-shiro in a while but it might be something like:

```
<a href="${shiro.principal.imgUrl}"/>
// or maybe
<a href="${shiro.principal['imgUrl]'}"/>
```